# Google Cloud Dataflow Stream + Batch

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am building an infrastructure where I'd like to sink hot and cold data separately. For the hot data, I'm writing my data to Cloud Spanner, and for the cold data, I'd like to write my data to something more persistent like BigQuery.

I'm consuming data from a streaming service, but I'd like to take advantage of BigQuery's caching mechanism - which won't be possible if I'm constantly streaming the cold data into BigQuery. My problem is around whether I can fork a stream pipeline into a batch pipeline and have the stream pipeline connected to Spanner and the batch pipeline connected to BigQuery.

I can envision something along the lines of writing the cold data into Cloud Storage and reading the data into BigQuery using a cron job, but is there a better/native way to achieve the Stream+Batch split?

Comment: Just as an aside.. if someone downvoted this question, I'd like to know why you'd think this deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that Dataflow has batch and streaming execution modes, you can use the streaming mode to do anything you can do in batch mode (costs and scalability may differ). Since your input is a stream, aka an unbounded data source, your pipeline will run in streaming mode automatically.

It sounds like the [`FILE_LOADS`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html#FILE_LOADS) method of writing to BigQuery may be what you want, and you can use [`withTriggeringFrequency`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withTriggeringFrequency-org.joda.time.Duration-) to manage how often data is written.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful API references. That's exactly what I'm looking for, but in a python library. I'm curious as to how Dataflow would charge me based on using withTriggeringFrequency? Would the costs be higher if the items are stuck in a pipeline on a timely basis,  e.g. trigger every hour?

Comment: You can use the pricing details at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#pricing_details to estimate your costs based on different approaches.